# How define starred form of command already using \SplitArgument?

Tags: macros, xparse

I have a command `\cont` used mainly in the form `\cont{X, Y}` and defined using `\SplitArgument`, as shown in the source below. How can I define a starred version `\cont*` of this command that does two things, as indicated:

- uses fences `\bigl[` and `\bigr]` instead of `(` and `)`; and
- uses 4 arguments rather than 2, which get grouped in the outout as shown in the output equation (3)?

If it helps, I'm willing to change the separator in the original `\cont` to a semicolon instead of a comma, so that I would use, for example, `\cont{X; Y}` and then use the starred form as, for example, `\cont*{X, x; Y, y}`.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{memoir}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{suffix}

\NewDocumentCommand{\cont}{ >{\SplitArgument{1}{,}} m }{\printcont#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\printcont}{mm}{{\mathcal{C}}({#1}\IfValueT{#2}{, {#2}})}

\newcommand{\contmaps}[2]{\mathcal{C}(#1, #2)}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\contmaps*[2]{\mathcal{C}\bigl[(#1),(#2)\bigr]}

% How define this?
%\WithSuffix\newcommand\cont* ..........

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{one}
\cont{X, Y}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{two}
\contmaps{X}{Y}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{three}
\contmaps*{X, x}{Y, y}
\end{equation}
How define \verb!\cont*! so next line gives same result as in equation (\ref{three})?
\\[6pt]
\mbox{}\qquad\verb!\cont*{X, x, Y, y}!

\end{document}
```

[image: to add starred form of command]

Comment: I removed my answer, but I add a comment: leave `\WithSuffix` alone.

Comment: @egreg: Would you kindly restore your answer, since its method of handling both commas and semicolons will still be of use to me?

Comment: No, sorry. You're asking something completely different.

Comment: @egreg: I posted as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/618768/13492 a modified version of my original question. I think your now-deleted answer here would respond to that.